# Errors in FFmpegSource2 plugin source filter for AviSynth

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, mpeg, avisynth

I was unable to read MTS or MP4 files in AviSynth. [Can AviSynth handle MTS files?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29123/can-avisynth-handle-mts-files/29126#29126) pointed to the [FFmpegSource2 filter](https://github.com/FFMS/ffms2), with [information on the wiki](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/FFmpegSource). I downloaded the plugin and pointed to it from the first line

```
LoadPlugin("C:\path\to\ffms2\x64\ffms2.dll")
DirectShowSource("\path\to\MP4\file")
```

This threw `error 0xc1`. [This thread](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/381913-avisynth-LoadPlugin-LSMASHSource-dll-error-0xc1) mentioned different architectures, so I tried the `x86` folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\AviSynth\plugins`).

After a little while, Windows Media Player opens a dialog with this text (translated to English):

```
Windows Media Player is unable to open the file. It's possible that Media Player
does not support this type of file or that you need a codec that is not
installed. [Close] [Help online]
```

How can I enable FFmpegSource2 plugin in AviSynth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The short answer, if you're familiar with AviSynth

You don't need to use `LoadPlugin()`, if you copy the four files in the plugin:

```
FFMS2.avsi
ffms2.dll
ffms2.lib
ffmsindex.exe
```

to the plugins directory of your AviSynth installation (see below for its location).

That's all. Then you directly use it in your AviSynth script calling its function(s), mostly the function

```
FFmpegSource2()
```

(or `FFMS2()`, which is the same, or `FFMS2("your_file.ts", atrack=-1)`) in concordance with documentation, but not `DirectShowSource()`.

---

#### The long answer

If you're beginning with AviSynth, the rest of the answer will walk you through the pitfalls.

**AviSynth versus AviSynth+**

AviSynth has two versions, denoted AviSynth and AviSynth+, at [the homepage](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page):

> **Official builds**
>   v.2.6.0 ST, 32-bit at SourceForge
>   ...
>   **Forks**
>   AviSynth+: new features, backward compatible.

AviSynth 2.6.0 is a very old version, in spite of its title as an "Official build". You're better off with the new version for `FFMS2`. Download it from the [official Github repo](https://github.com/AviSynth/AviSynthPlus/releases) pointed to from [the homepage](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page).

**The directory of plugins for AviSynth+**

When you install the Github fork of AviSynth+, check the box `Customize plugins directory` to find the paths without changing them. Copy the four plugin files mentioned above to `C:\Program Files (x86)\AviSynth+\plugins+` or to `C:\Program Files (x86)\AviSynth+\plugins64+`, depending on your version of Windows. The `+` at the end of the directory is for AviSynth+ instead of AviSynth.

The file `FFMS2.avsi` in the FFMS2 plugin is the same for both architectures.

If you copy it to the wrong directory, you may see this in Windows Media Player:

```
Cannot load a 64 bit DLL in 32 bit Avisynth: 
    'C:/Program Files (x86)/AviSynth+/plugins+/ffms2.dll'
```

which means that you should move those files to `C:\Program Files (x86)\AviSynth+\plugins64+\`.

**Choose the appropriate media player**

If you play the `.avs` file with Windows Media Player, you may see  a `.MP4.ffindex` file for each file that you use with `FFMS2()` and the `.avs` file shows no image and no sound, only a musical note that looks like standard Windows.

Windows Media Player is not able to play back `.avs` files. Use Media Player Classic — you may get it with very useful [K-Lite Mega Codec Pack](https://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm) — simply download and install it. Be sure to select the **Mega** pack, because the Basic pack doesn't contain the player.

**Convert the script to a media file**

Another possibility is to convert the `.avs` file into a media file, for example with [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i your.avs output.mp4
```

FFmpeg chooses appropriate codecs automatically by the extension of the output file) and play back the result in (almost) any media player.

You may download the ready-to-use FFmpeg from [Zeranoe's page](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) — just unpack the downloaded archive file and add the path to `ffmpeg.exe` into your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: You still used `DirectShowSource` filter. Use `FFMS2` instead: `FFMS2(your_file.ts, atrack=-1)`. You needn't use `LoadPlugin()`, it will be autoloaded by using `FFMS2`.

Comment: It means that the directory into your copied file is NOT an autoload directory. I don't know which version of AviSynth do you use — see e.g. [Plugin Autoloader](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/AviSynth%2B#Plugin_Autoloader). If you have a very old version, consider to download a newer one: [Avisynth+ r2772-MT](https://github.com/pinterf/AviSynthPlus/releases/tag/r2772-MT) 64-bit + 32-bit (download links are at the end), or [AviSynth+ 3.4.0](https://github.com/AviSynth/AviSynthPlus/releases/tag/v3.4.0) (only 32-bit IMHO).

Comment: No, [AviSynth+ 3.4.0](https://github.com/AviSynth/AviSynthPlus/releases/tag/v3.4.0) is both 64-bit + 32-bit, too.

Comment: Which version of AviSynth do you have? (Put the `version` as a single row in your text editor, save it as `version.avs` and play it back.)

Comment: It's very old version, in spite it's an "Official build" one. Use "Forks -> Latest release" (which is the same 3.4.0 as I already wrote in my previous comment) and download the .exe file (the installer).

Comment: See my extended answer — all things are now good, only Windows Media Player is not appropriate for `.avs` files.

Comment: @miguelmorin, it will be nice from you and helpful for other people. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: @miguelmorin, other possibility is to write the summary of the discussion as your own answer, and I will it vote up (and maybe other people, too). Yes, you may answer your own question.

Comment: @miguelmorin — yes, it would be better to make it as a new question, because **1.** you will have a larger space to express your problem, **2.** if I will not answer your question, other people may do it, **3.** everyone may vote your answer.

Comment: I added a new question about 32-bit AviSynth+ https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30042/how-to-install-avisynth-32-bit